# HTML/CSS Hover Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a drop down menu using HTML and CSS, but I can't seem to get it working.
I've tried using 
 `position: absolute;`, but I do not want the drop down menu to be position in that type of way, because it will not function properly if I decide to resize the window.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to make a hover-able drop down menu, in HTML and CSS, without using absolute positioning.

Here is my current code:

## CSS/HTML

```css
/* dropdown-style.css */
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: aqua; 
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    /* box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377); */
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
   /* width: 100%; */
    /* margin-left: 30%; */
}

.menu-dropdown-button {
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 1.5in;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-dropdown-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(9, 209, 209);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-dropdown-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(12, 184, 184);
    cursor: progress;
}

#dropdown-button:hover + .dropdown-menu  {
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}


.dropdown-button {
  display: block;
}



/* menu-style.css */
.menu {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 11;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    float: left;
}

.menu-button {
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 1.5in;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(9, 209, 209);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(12, 184, 184);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu-style.css">
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" >
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" >
         -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropdown-style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-menu" class="menu">
            <button class="menu-button">Home</button>
            <button class="menu-button">Forums</button>
            <button class="menu-button">Store</button>
            <button id="dropdown-button" class="menu-button">More <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></button>
            
            <div id="more-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <button class="menu-button dropdown-button">Apply</button>
                <button class="menu-button dropdown-button">Appeal</button>
                <button class="menu-button dropdown-button">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="type/javascript" src="js/dropmenu-script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll often use `position: absolute` and then use `margin-top` and `margin-left` to move the element relative to its position instead of absoluting it. It seems like you might be able to use that

Comment: Does that method work when you resize the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are expecting. If you move the dropdown menu inside the button, it will work as you expected.

```css
/* dropdown-style.css */
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: aqua; 
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    /* box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377); */
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
   /* width: 100%; */
    /* margin-left: 30%; */
}

.menu-dropdown-button {
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 1.5in;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-dropdown-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(9, 209, 209);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-dropdown-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(12, 184, 184);
    cursor: progress;
}

#dropdown-button:hover + .dropdown-menu  {
    display: block;
}


.menu-button:hover #more-dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

#more-dropdown-menu li{
width:90px;
}

.dropdown-button {
  display: block;
}



/* menu-style.css */
.menu {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 11;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    float: left;
}

.menu-button {
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 1.5in;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(9, 209, 209);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(12, 184, 184);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu-style.css">
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" >
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" >
         -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropdown-style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-menu" class="menu">
            <button class="menu-button">Home</button>
            <button class="menu-button">Forums</button>
            <button class="menu-button">Store</button>
            <button id="dropdown-button" class="menu-button">More <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
             <ul id="more-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="menu-button dropdown-button">Apply</li>
                <li class="menu-button dropdown-button">Appeal</li>
                <li class="menu-button dropdown-button">Contact</li>
            </ul>
            
            </button>
            
           
        </div>
        <script type="type/javascript" src="js/dropmenu-script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```